# Number of electrons flowing in a circuit

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

Does the number of electrons flowing in a circuit get affected when we turn on the light? If yes or no, then why.

Help please.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE. Please look around and take the tour. As your question stands, it is unclear (what light?). In addition, it is not in line with our homework policy, since it shows no work and does not illuminate any physics. I am down voting for those reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the amount of (molecules of) water in a hose. Does it change when we start pumping it around?